# Control component visibility based on screen width

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, styled-components

I have a Wrapper component which contains filters. It appears when I run a `openMobileFilters()` function and disappears when I run `closeMobileFilters()`. The whole component takes a full page and I need to run `closeMobileFilters()` when the screen is bigger than `993px`.

`openMobileFilters()` and `closeMobileFilters()` change a state which depends on whether the component is displayed.

Here is my code:

```
const Wrapper = styled.div`
  @media only screen and (min-width: 993px) {
    //can I put somehow the closeMobileFilters() function here?
  }
`;

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  closeMobileFilters: () => dispatch(closeMobileFiltersAction()),
});

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(MobileFilters);
```

I am using React, Redux and styled components.

I know that I can put there just `display: none;` but I need to run this function.

**EDIT - problem solved**

I used `import useResizeObserver from "@react-hook/resize-observer";` which gave me abilities to use this code:

```
const useSize = (target) => {
  const [size, setSize] = useState();

  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    setSize(target.current.getBoundingClientRect());
  }, [target]);

  useResizeObserver(target, (entry) => setSize(entry.contentRect));
  return size;
};

const target = useRef(null);
const size = useSize(target);

<Wrapper ref={target}>
</Wrapper>
```

and just called my `closeMobileFilters()` function like this:

```
if (size?.width === 0) {
    closeMobileFilters();
  }
```

Comment: No you can't write js in css.

Comment: No you can't write js in css.

Comment: Can you, please, elaborate a bit, what is it you're trying to achieve (what exactly means 'I need to run closeMobileFilters() when the screen is bigger than 993px')? Preliminary, you can pass props to your styled component and consume those by arbitrary JS within your string template.

Comment: Firstly when I click on button which should open the window with filters, it runs openMobileFilters() and sets the state to true. In my Filters component I have a button to close it (to send closeMobileFilters() and change the state to false), but I want also to change the state when user change the browser screen width to >993px, so if he will come back to width <993px the window will be closed.

Comment: It should looks like on this page: https://www.klekt.com/list?categories=sneakers

Comment: On this page when you reduce the width of browser screen to about <960px, click on the filters button, the filters window will be showed, but when you increase the width and reduce one more time, it will be hidden.

Comment: You can use a ResizeObserver within a `useEffect` for this. Docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Resize_Observer_API

Answer (score 2):

#### TL;DR

You may find a sample implementation [over here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-r19nim?file=src%2Fapp.js)

#### General Explanation

Normally, your UI would respond to crossing typical [breakpoints](https://material.io/design/layout/responsive-layout-grid.html#breakpoints) (screen widths ranges) and as long as you may need multiple scattered components responding to screen width changes, you might want to keep track of the current width in your Redux state.

Back to your question, if you would have current breakpoint (for simplicity sake, let's assume it's just wide screen and narrow one, less than 993px wide) in your state, you may access that value from within the component that renders the modal window, populated with filters and use conditional rendering to render that modal window **only** for narrow screen.

So, it's not like *'window resize should trigger dispatch of state update that will set modal window closed'*, but rather like *`window resize should trigger screen width update within the state and modal window (possibly, along with other components) should respond to screen width change with closing'*

#### Step by step implementation

What you need is to

- attach (with `useEffect()` hook) to some root component (wrapping your entire app) event listener that will respond to `resize` event by dispatching an action that will modify the state according to the current screen width

```js
const setWidth = () => {
    const isWide = window.innerWidth > 993;
    const width = isWide ? 'wide' : 'narrow';

    dispatch({
      type: SET_WIDTH,
      width
    });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('resize', setWidth);
    return () => window.removeEventListener('resize', setWidth);
  }, []);
```

- in addition to the state variable that you toggle with modal open/close buttons, modal component should render conditionally based on width, e.g.

```js
export const FiltersModal = () => {
  const isWide = useSelector(state => state?.width === 'wide');
  const isVisible = useSelector(state => state?.filtersVisible);
  return !!isWide && !!isVisible && <div>I am filters modal</div>;
};
```

> ***Note:*** above implementation is designed only to deliver the general idea, your production app would probably need to use [debouncing](https://css-tricks.com/debouncing-throttling-explained-examples/) for proper `resize` event handling, leverage [reselect](https://www.npmjs.com/package/reselect) library, arrange the code appropriately, use type safety (TypeScript), etc.

> ***Note:*** if you would still need to pass property to your styled component and adjust its appearance, based on state, you may check out `<MainWrapper />` component's implementation

Answer (score 1):

You should not do this with css (and especially, not during something executed during render).

Look into doing this purely in JS using a ResizeObserver.